# Git push my branch changes to another repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am in a Git repository, and in my branch there are some commits. I
need to push only this branch's changes into another remote repository. How can I achieve this?

I have tried the command `git push git@bitbucket.org:XXX/XXX.git launchpad-issues`.

This command pushes the whole repository, but I am looking to just push the changes on one branch only.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.  This involves multiple repositories.

Comment: @GKFX: that particular question is due to the way very ancient (pre-2.0) versions of Git behave. It's possible that yala ramesh has an ancient version of Git, though.

Comment: @ZachPosten Many thanks, I was confused by the grammar of "another my repository"; will delete original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another remote to your local git and then push to it.  Say you want to push the `foo` branch

```
# Add another remote called 'my-other-repo'
git remote add my-other-repo git@bitbucket.org:XXX/XXX.git

# Push the foo branch to my-other-repo
git push my-other-repo foo
```

And if you want you can optionally remove the remote afterward

```
git remote remove my-other-repo
```

Comment: Thanks @Zach Posten i am do like this it will push the my complete repository commits in this branch.when i am check in repro2  this foo branch showing with all commits of repro1(master commits + foo branch commits ).

Comment: @yalaramesh What I put above will only push the `foo` branch, and no other branch.  But you are correct that it will push the entire history of that branch.  There really isn't another option because each commit is just a patch on the one before it.  You can always just copy the files you're interested in over to the other repo.